# Opping Deopping Users on twitch.tv using pircbot

Tags: java

I just started creating my own ircBot for my Twitch.tv Channel and i would like to add
a Function to set Moderator statur or remove it through a simple !op/deop username message in my Chat.

This is what i came up with til now:

(i also created an string where "owner" is defined as my accounts name for checking if its me who want to op/deop some1)

```
        if (message.startsWith("!op")) {
            if(sender.equals(owner))
            {
                String userToOp = message.split(" ")[1];
                op(channel, userToOp);
                sendMessage(channel, "Grant Moderator Status to: " + userToOp);
            }
            else
            {
                sendMessage(channel, "You are not allowed to use this Command!");
//                sendMessage(channel, "/timeout "+sender+"");
            }
        }

        if (message.startsWith("!deop")) {
            if(sender.equals(owner))
            {
                String userToOp = message.split(" ")[1];
                deOp(channel, userToOp);
                sendMessage(channel, "Removed Moderator Status from: "+ userToOp);
            }
            else
            {
                sendMessage(channel, "You are not allowed to use this Command!");
//              sendMessage(channel, "/timeout "+sender+"");
            }
        }
```

It works almost everything fine..

The only problem that occurs is that the users actually doesnt get the Moderator status out of that script. (the bot has moderator status to use the op/deop cmd)

on twitch, the regular cmds to type in chat for modding/demodding some1 are /mod & /unmod
so i maybe thought that the pircbot standard op/deop cmds arent working.

So i may be able to let the bot do this commands instead BUT dont write them into the channel? if yes how would that look like?

if any1 could help me that would be awesome :D
(and sorry for my bad english :p)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the twitch chat through an IRC client, you have to send commands to the twitch servers with "." as a prefix. Making your bot call the sendMessage(channel, message) method with ".slow 100" as message for instance, will invoke slow mode (with 100 sec post delay) for normal users in the chat. This message will *not* be visible in the chat! This goes for everything posted with a "." prefix, valid command or not.

So you can OP someone by changing the code:

```
    if (message.startsWith("!op")) {
        if(sender.equals(owner))
        {
            String userToOp = message.split(" ")[1];
            sendMessage(channel, ".op " + userToOp)
            sendMessage(channel, "Grant Moderator Status to: " + userToOp);
        }
    }
```